# How to reduce opentelemetry-collector container's memory usage

Tags: go, open-telemetry

I have deployed **opentelemetry-collector** as a container by pulling the image from https://hub.docker.com/r/otel/opentelemetry-collector/tags. I checked the container's memory usage using **docker stats** command and I got **MEM USAGE / LIMIT -> 15.3MiB / 7.667GiB**

Is there any possibility to reduce the memory usage for this default image to **below 10MiB**

I want to reduce the opentelemetry-collector container's memory usage to below 10MiB

Comment: 10MiB is really low. You will need really aggressive config, e.g. disable batching, minimal exporters, ... You didn't show your config, otel version, architecture, so it is really hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `--memory=10m` to your `docker run` command.

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/

Now - this isn't magic. If the process needs more than that to run then it will just crash.

If that is the case, then you will need to look at changing the configuration of the service and/or possibly its source code.

Comment: This is not a solution to `reduce` memory, but to `limit` memory.

Comment: From the point of view of the host machine the memory the container is using has been reduced. Presumably deployment is going to happen with containers otherwise you wouldn't test+measure memory usage via docker. If the service is written to adapt its allocation to the memory available and can do so then usage is reduced. If it cannot then as stated it will crash.